# Laravel - Middleware para usuarios registrados y no registrados

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-6, laravel-4

Tengo un proyecto en laravel donde el usuario se autentifica y guardo el inicio en la sessión.

**La ruta es esta**

```
Route::get('login', function()
{
    return view('pages.login');
})->name('login');
```

El controlador que hace la acción de loggeo es esta

```
public function login(Request $request)
{

    $user = User::where('email',$request->get('email'))
        ->where('password',$request->get('password'))
        ->first();


    if (null !== $user) {

        $request->session()->put('login_email', $request->get('email'));
        $request->session()->put('user_id', $user->id);

        $userHasProfile = UserProfile::where('user_id',$user->id)->first();
        $routines = Routine::where('user_id',$user->id)->count();
        $diets = Diet::where('user_id',$user->id)->count();

        if (null !== $userHasProfile) {
            $request->session()->put('userProfile', $userHasProfile);
            $request->session()->put('userHasProfile', true);
        }
        else {
            $request->session()->put('userHasProfile', false);
        }


        return view('pages.home-user');
    }


    return view('pages.error');
}
```

Esta función mira si el usuario es correcto , si lo es pone una serie de variables en sesión y sino lo es lo redirige a una página de error. (esto esta funcionando)

Ahora me falta ver como hacer para proteger las rutas, es decir tengo ciertas rutas del proyecto que si el usuario no esta loggeado no debe poder entrar, o se le debe redigir hacia el login.

Entiendo que debo hacerlo con un middleware pero no veo la forma de ponerlo al código que estoy planteando.

Gracias por adelantado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dentro de tu controlador puedes crear un método constructor para invocar al método `middleware` y como argumento pasarle el nombre del que vas a usar así:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware("auth");
}
```

Ahora para proteger las rutas tienes 2 opciones:

- except: para indicar a que métodos no se les aplicará el middleware
- only: para indicar los métodos a los que se les aplicaría el middleware

En ambos casos puedes pasar los métodos dentro de un array si necesitas aplicar o no a múltiples de ellos

Si elijes la segunda quedaría así:

```
$this->middleware('auth')->only(['index', 'show']);
```

**Fuente**

- [Middleware Controller](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/controllers#controller-middleware)